# How to verify 'Open xdg-open popup' in Chrome via Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a testcase where if a certain link is clicked a "Open xdg-open" Popup is triggered in the chrome browser.

I want to verify in my testcase if an "Open xdg-open" Popup actually appears.

I tried to use the following Code block:

```
boolean check;
try {
     driver.switchTo().alert();
     check = true;
} catch(NoAlertPresentException e) {
   check = false;
}
```

However the "Open xdg-open" Popup triggers the NoAlertPresentExcpetion even though it appears in the browser.

Do you have any clue how I can verify the "Open xdg-open" Popup?

Comment: Can you share a link to that page? I suggested the answer but to give an exact answer we need to see what actually goes on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because it's not a DOM element you can switch to it. This kind of `xdg-open` alert happens whenever it wants to handle a protocol defined by user preferences. It could be any of (afp, Tel, disk, file, hcp, ...)

You can use `ChromeOptions` in order to exclude these kind of schemes

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option( "prefs", {'protocol_handler.excluded_schemes.hcp': false})
```

You should change the protocol above with whatever protocol is on your side or use this code which exclude list of schemes

```
driver.execute_script("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }")

prefs = {"protocol_handler.excluded_schemes":{"afp":True,"data":True,"disk":True,"disks":True,"file":True,"hcp":True,"intent":True, "itms-appss":True, "itms-apps":True,"itms":True,"market":True,"javascript":True,"mailto":True,"ms-help":True,"news":True,"nntp":True,"shell":True,"sip":True,"snews":False,"vbscript":True,"view-source":True,"vnd":{"ms":{"radio":True}}}}    

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
```

Comment: not working for me